# Value of an element of a struct is setting before return but not when it is returned

Tags: c, struct, deserialization

I've got this code below which takes a 131 byte buffer over the network and stores the decoded values into the elements in a struct, but for the first element, `protocol_version`, I set the value to the element in the buffer but it fails to set the value of `protocol_version` to the first element in the buffer. The struct is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
  short protocol_version;
  char username[64];
  char verification_key[64];
  char unused;
} player_identification;
```

And the code is here:

```
player_identification *parse_player_identification(char *buffer) {
  player_identification *pkt = malloc(sizeof(player_identification));
  pkt->protocol_version = buffer[0];
  printf("0x0%x\n", pkt->protocol_version); // THIS PRINTS OUT 0x07 WHICH IS CORRECT!

  char buf[64];
  for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            buf[i] = buffer[i + 1];
    }
  buf[64] = 0;
  strcpy(pkt->username, trim_whitespace(&buf));

  char buf2[64];
  for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            buf2[i] = buffer[i + 1 + 64];
    }
  buf2[64] = 0;
  strcpy(pkt->verification_key, trim_whitespace(&buf2));

  pkt->unused = buffer[130];
  return pkt;
}
```

Note how I print it out, it prints the value of `0x07` which is the constant value that `buffer[0]` will always be but it is always `0x00`. With GDB it says that the pointer is `0x00` (null) so I am unable to read the contents of the memory address. Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you didn't verify that field at the *end* of your function as well? Strip all the memory buffer circus acts out of that function, leaving only the `protocol_version` assignment. Check the result. if it is correct, start adding things back. My guess is you're blowing past one of your character buffers during a copy and overwriting your version field. And since we're not provided a [minimal, **complete**, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), guesses are about all you're going to get. (which makes for a *terrible* question for others to learn from, by the way).

Comment: @WhozCraig, after commenting out both of the circus acts of string manipulation, I have in fact properly set the `protocol_version`. What is wrong with both of my string functions that could be overwriting the version field?

Comment: And btw, `buf[64] = 0;` and `buf2[64] = 0;` both invoke *undefined behavior*. Those buffers are both only subscriptable through 0..63.

Comment: @WhozCraig, that fixed it. Maybe write a full answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these:

```
buf[64] = 0;
....
buf2[64] = 0;
```

invoke *undefined behavior*. Those buffers are only `64` elements wide. Native arrays of size `N` in C are subscriptable from 0...(N-1). Both of those statements write one element past that, and from there the remaining behavior of your program is left to fairies.